# Why is intersection of two 3D objects zig-zag?

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, direct3d

I have no previous experience with DirectX, I was just assigned to a project that needs quick modification(s).

I'm currently facing this problem: I have a surface that is virtually a textured plane, defined by 1024x1024 points (the terrain). It renders fine and I'm happy with it. Then there is an orthogonal yellow semitransparent plane which intersects the terrain. From side, it looks like in the following picture (notice how flat the terrain is):

[image]

However, if I look at the same scene from a different angle, I can see that two planes intersect in a zig-zag way, like one of them wouldn't really be planar. This annoys me. It looks like a naive painter's algorithm was used to intersect the terrain's individual triangles with the yellow plane.

[image]

Any idea how to convince DirectX to create a smooth intersection? (May it be just a matter of one parameter which I can't find?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why?

Insufficient Z buffer resolution.

> May it be just a matter of one parameter which I can't find?

The main parameter is world*view*projection matrix you pass to your vertex shaders.

One way to fix, limit Z size of the view area by moving near and far Z clipping planes close together.

Or if you working with large terrain and want to see scenes measured in kilometers, you need logarithmic depth or something similar, see [this article](https://outerra.blogspot.com/2012/11/maximizing-depth-buffer-range-and.html) for comparison of several approaches.

Comment: Many, many thanks! Once I changed the current resolution from 16bits to 24 bits, the problem immediatelly disappeared! :-)